# Access array of objects by index in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a `react.js` project and I need to access an array of objects. I get the objects from an external `URL` and there's no issue there. Inside my `component`'s `render` method I can see the array:

```
  const array = this.state.data.myArray;
  console.log({array});
```

Now I try to look at the first object:

```
  console.log({array}[0]);
```

but it's `undefined`.

I tried various combinations with or without the curly brackets but it's always undefined, or gives an `unexpected token` error.

How do I get to the array's objects?

EDIT:

Looks like my `render` method is called twice. The first time it's with the array `undefined` and the second time it has data, but by now it's no longer rendering.

Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react'
class Hello extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { data: [] };
    }


   async componentDidMount() {
      const url = 'http://localhost:9000/SomeJson/id';
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({ data });
      console.log(data); // data shows up in the console
   }

  render() {
      alert(this.state.data.theArray);

  return(
      <div><h2>hello</h2></div>
   );

  }
}
export default Hello;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: it should be `array[0]` if `array` is a valid Array. can you show output for `console.log(array);`

Comment: No idea why you're putting curly brackets there, all it does is initialize an object with key `array` with value of your array. `console.log(array[0])` is probably fine, if it isn't, you should show the output for `console.log(array);` as stated above

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my `render` method is called twice. I edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

`const { myArray = [] } = this.state.data || {}`
You should check for data key to be a valid object and then destructure myArray out of it and then if myArray is undefined then initialise it with empty array.

Comment: Thanks @Muhamman Ali. Looks like my `render` method is called twice. I edited the question with more information.

Comment: instantiate your data state with empty object instead of empty array.